# How to sort a table in SQL?

Tags: sql, t-sql, sorting

I have the following table:

```
table 1
Row   volume   part 1   part 2   part 3 
1      520     2        5        3 
2     1020     3        6        7 
3      100     1        9        2 
4      200     9        2        1
```

Now I want the table above (Table 1), the following conditions would sort:
First, most of the times was produced and arranged by the volume the show in the first record. Then, sort by parts 1 then part 2 and then part 3.
the output table was as follows:

```
table2
Row   volume   part 1   part 2   part 3 
2     1020     3        6        7 
4      200     9        2        1 
3      100     1        9        2 
1      520     2        5        3
```

If I'm sort of on the volume then part 1 and part 2 and part 3 of the first column of the table in terms of order volume and then the rest of the items practices sort you are the created table below (Table 3).

```
table 3
Row   volume   part 1   part 2   part 3 
2     1020     3        6        7 
1      520     2        5        3 
4      200     9        2        1 
3      100     1        9        2
```

While I want table 2 as a output.

Please help me.

Comment: Order by with CASE and sub-queries, lots of work...

Comment: This is a very arcane requirement.  Can you explain why you need this?

Comment: Why the `vb.net` tag? You need a query to do this or how to do this with vb.net code?

Comment: Are "Row+volume+part 1+part 2+part 3" each separate columns?

Comment: yes each separate is a columns.

Comment: i'm need the using of select sql for table columns sort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with cte1 (row,part 1, part 2, part 3, part 4, rownum)
as
(
select top 1 *,part 1 as rownum from table1
where part 1=(select MAX(part 1) from table1)

union all

select top 1 *,part 2 as rownum from table1
where part 2=(select MAX(part 2) from table1)

union all

select top 1 *,part 3 as rownum from table1
where part 3=(select MAX(part 3) from table1)

union all

select top 1 *,part 4 as rownum from table1
where part 4=(select MAX(part 4) from table1)


),
cte2(row,part 1, part 2, part 3, part 4)
as(
select distinct row,part 1, part 2, part 3, part 4 from cte1) 
,
cte3(row,part 1, part 2, part 3, part 4, rownum)
as(
select *, ROW_NUMBER() over (order by row) rownum from cte2 )
,
cte4(row,part 1, part 2, part 3, part 4)
as(
select top 100 percent cte1.row, cte1.part 1, cte1.part 2, cte1.part 3, cte1.part 4 from cte1
join cte3 on cte1.rownum=cte3.rownum
order by cte1.rownum
)
select * from cte4
union all
select * from table1
where row not in (select row from cte4)

---